# Code style preferences using Sicstus and Eclipse (Spider)

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, web-crawler, galileo, sicstus-prolog

I am currently using Sicstus Prolog VC9 4.1.1 within Eclipse Galileo (Spider). I have a very newbie question: how would I automatically control indentation and in general code style preferences?

Comment: Thanks for this, I always appreciate when people take time to read my questions and include useful additions/changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is only one setting that affects coding style, the default indentation level.

Open the Preferences in Eclipse. Under SICStus Prolog you will find all SPIDER-related preferences. There you can also change some of the highlighting preferences.

More powerful source code formatting is planned.

(I am one of the SICStus Prolog developers and I am responsible for SPIDER.)

Comment: Thanks, that was useful, I look forward to seeing new SPIDER's functionalities. So far, I am really pleased with the whole environment. 

I.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about SPIDER but you can adjust Eclipse to be Emacs Compatible editor. Emacs also can understand you are writing code in sicstus so your Eclipse can become a very friendly environment for you coding in sicstus as well as keeping the indentation
also try using Cmd+Shift+F in case you are Mac user